# How to prepare Django for a possible slashdotting?

Tags: django, performance, optimization, traffic, webfaction

I would like to prepare my website for a possible influx in traffic. This is my first time using Django as a framework, so I'm unsure of the modifications that should be made to assure that I'm ready and won't go down. What are some of the common things one can do to prepare a Django website for production-level traffic?

I'm also wondering what to expect in terms of traffic numbers. I'm currently hosted at Webfaction with 600GB/month of traffic. Will this quickly run out? Are there statistics on how big 'slashdotted' events are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use [memcache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?#memcached) and [caching middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?#the-per-site-cache).
2. Be sure to [offload serving statics](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production).
3. Use [CDN for statics](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-from-a-cloud-service-or-cdn). This doesn't directly affect Django, but will reduce your network traffic.

Anything beyond that — read up what others are using:

- [Scaling Django Web Apps By Mike Malone](http://highscalability.com/blog/2009/5/17/scaling-django-web-apps-by-mike-malone.html)
- [Instagram Architecture](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/4/16/instagram-architecture-update-whats-new-with-instagram.html)
- [DISQUS Architecture](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/10/26/scaling-disqus-to-75-million-comments-and-17000-rps.html)

Comment: Thanks for those links. I'm currently looking at cloudfare for a CDN. I'll be checking how I can easily implement memcaching with my host, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are at Webfaction you have an easy answer for handling your statics:

1. Create a Static-only application. (Not the Static CGI/PHP app)
2. Add it under you current website.
3. Put all of your statics under it (or symlink to them, which is what I do).

This will serve all statics through their nginx frontend -- blindingly fast.

Regarding your bandwidth allocation:

You don't say what type of content you are offering. If it is anything even slightly vanilla you are unlikely to approach 600GB/mo. I have one customer who offers adult-oriented videos teaching tantric sex techniques and their video bandwidth (for both free & member-only videos) is about 400-450GB/mo. The HTML portion of the site (with tons of images) runs about 50-60GB/mo.

Comment: My current set up is the one you mention. I have a seperate app serving my static files. However, this is still contributing to my monthly bandwidth (if only a little). So a CDN might be beneficial for me in that sense. In terms of bandwidth, I have a mostly simple HTML/jQuery and Bootstrap environment. Thanks for your stats, I'm a little more at ease now :)

Comment: @Peter Interesting stat. By the way, adult content is prohibited on webfaction (http://www.webfaction.com/aup), isn't it? How could your customer host on webfaction then? Just curious.